# Looping through a nested object

Tags: javascript, object

Currently I have an object, and I am looping through it to get outputs like so:

```js
var obj = {
  "first": {
    "Bob": {
      "1": "foo",
      "2": "bar"
    },
    "Jim": {
      "1": "baz"
    }
  },
  "second": {
    "Bob": {
      "1": "qux"
    },
    "Jim": {
      "1": "quux"
    },
  },
}

for (let position in obj) {
  console.log(`In ${position} position`);
  let pos = obj[position];
  for (let name in pos) {
    person = pos[name];
    for (let item in person) {
      let thing = person[item];
      console.log(`${position} ${name} ${item} ${thing}`)
    }
  }
}
```

However, I feel that this might be a messy way of doing it since I am nesting multiple `for` loops, is there a cleaner way of doing this? Perhaps utilising ES6/ES7+/etc. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach by checking the actual item and if it is an object, then iterate this object by keeping the path to this object.

Later use path and value.

```js
function iter(object, path = []) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(k => {
        var temp = path.concat(k);
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            iter(object[k], temp);
            return;
        }
        console.log(path.join('>'), object[k]);
    });
}


var data = { first: { Bob: { "1": "foo", "2": "bar" }, Jim: { "1": "baz" } }, second: { Bob: { "1": "qux" }, Jim: { "1": "quux" } } };

iter(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```